# Auto add a new row into Repeater Control when it has a new row inserted into SQL Server 2008 DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, repeater

This is so hard to understand, I'll try to describe my problem so clearly.

I have a Table in SQL DB:

```
COMMENT(idcom, content,user,idtopic);
```

I use a Repeater Control to display all the comment in Database:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
<table>
      <tr>
         <td>
             &nbsp;
         </td>
         <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblcontent" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("content") %>'>
            </asp:Label>
       </td>
        <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbluser" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("user") %>'>
                </asp:Label>
       </td>
</tr>
</table>
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My problem is: When client `add a new comment (in another page)`--> insert a new row into `COMMENT` table---> I have to load all the comment into Repeater again `(both old comments and new comments)`.---> therefor, I use `<UpdatePanel>` and `<Timer Control>` Ajax Toolkit to update every 10sec. It's so amateur and not a good solution.

How can I just only load the new comment (new row) into the Repeater in every 10sec.

I always think Repeater is fixed and we cannot insert the single row.

Help! Can you give me some advice to insert single row into Repeater by load data from Database (not input directly)???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the best way to do this is with some Javascript/jQuery plugin + AJAX queries. ASP.NET Webforms does not usually works that way (it is prefered from the webform point of view to go through the entire page lifecycle for each update).

Answer (score -1):

When you first populate your repeater, store the List and the biggest IdComm in variables, So you will use it in  all subsequent selects you do in Database again. 
Use the IdComm stored as a parameter and get all the new comments with IdComm bigger than the IDComm you have passed as parameter.
After that, add this new lines in the first list you have requested in the first request and populate the Repeater again in this updatePanel you are using.